# MongoDB: How to create an object that has an array of objects as a field?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, mongodb

I have this schema:

```
const SingleExerciseSchema = new Schema({
    exerciseName: { type: String },
    setLog: [{
        weight: { type: Number },
        sets: { type: Number },
        reps: { type: Number },
    }],
});
```

Then I get data like this, as a json:

```
const DATA = [
    { exerciseName: "Squat",
      setLog: [
        {weight: 65, sets: 1, reps: 5},
        {weight: 55, sets: 2, reps: 5},
        {weight: 45, sets: 1, reps: 5},
      ]
    },
    { exerciseName: "Overhead Press",
      setLog: [
        {weight: 27.5, sets: 1, reps: 5}
      ]
    }
  ];
```

I want to loop over the data and create my SingleExercise objects from it.

Like this:

```
const exerciseObjectList = (req.body).map(
    (exerciseLog) => new SingleExercise({
      exerciseName: req.body.exerciseName,
      setLog: // stuck here
    })
```

However, I'm not sure to update/access the setLog fields, syntax wise. I want something like this:

```
const exerciseObjectList = (req.body).map(
    (exerciseLog) => new SingleExercise({
      exerciseName: req.body.exerciseName,
      setLog: {
        (req.body.setLog).map(
          (set) => {
            weight: set.weight,
            sets: set.sets,
            reps: set.reps,
          }
        )
      }
    })
  );
```

but it's obviously wrong syntax.

Edit: I actually had a stupid mistake in my code, I wrote req.body.exerciseName instead of exerciseLog.exerciseName in my loop.
Also, I just went with

```
setLog: exerciseLog.setLog
```

and it works (instead of accessing each field inside setLog separately).
I still don't know how to access each field separately, but for now, I don't need to do that.

Fixed code:

```
const exerciseObjectList = (req.body).map(
    (exerciseLog) => new SingleExercise({
      exerciseName: exerciseLog.exerciseName,
      setLog: exerciseLog.setLog,
    }));
```

Comment: What result did you get? What do you expect? Can you add more debugging details?

Comment: My code wouldn't compile, I don't know the syntax of how to update a field of an object that's inside an array. I went with just assigning to setLog the whole array of objects, without accessing them one by one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you can just map over the req.body and add the element inside each `new SingleExercise`

```
const exerciseObjectList = req.body.map(exercise => new SingleExercise(exercise))
```